# How to get Email ID from the Facebook SDK in Android Application?

Tags: android, facebook, email, permissions

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
    {


        GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject me, GraphResponse response) {
                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                            textView.setText("Error");
                        } else {
                            String email = me.optString("email").toString();
                            textView1.setText(email);

                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();


    }
```

Comment: what is the problem then? your code looks correct.

Comment: @Krupal I can't get the users email address to a text field?

Comment: have you take e-mail permission

Comment: @Singhak Yes, I got the permission from FB application.

Comment: Check in Log what data are u gettin in json

Comment: it may be possible that your fb setting not allow to give email id

Comment: use other user for login

Comment: Thanks @Singhak yeah the problem was with the FB user login